# reading data from txt file, works in Visual Studio but fails in Xcode

Tags: c++, xcode, text

```
#include <stream>  
#include <iostream>
#include <stream>
#include <iosfwd>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    string op = "original";
    ifstream file;
    file.open("sample.txt");
    if(!file) {
        cout << "Error: unable to open file." << endl;
    }
    else {
        while(!file.eof()) {
            file >> op;
            cout << op << endl;
        }
    }

    file.close();
    return 0;
}
```

sample.txt only contains the word `five`

I run this code in Visual Studio and the output is

```
five
```

I run the exact same code(direct copy and paste, and data.txt is added for sure) in Xcode and what gets printed in the command line is

```
original
```

The bug I see is that

```
file >> op
```

never really worked in Xcode. WHY?

Comment: How can anything get printed? That definitely isn't valid C++.

Comment: Please paste **the real code** into your question.  This isn't your program.

Comment: `while(!file.eof()){` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong

Comment: txt on a mac using text edit has a different format. You are expecting  ASCII, and that file is probably UTF-8

Comment: @Afonso ASCII and UTF-8 are the same for "five".

Comment: @DrewDormann  This is exactly my code. I am new to C++ and Xcode. I am trying things out.

Comment: @user3703783, No one knows what the includes are supposed to be, least of all the compiler. And `<stream>` isn't a standard header (there's `iostream`, `istream`, `ostream`, `sstream`, `strstream`, `fstream`, and maybe others). But sincerely, thanks for coming back.

Comment: The newest one makes the most sense. If the read fails, `op` is left unchanged (not 100% sure how well that applies to C++11 with `char *`). You never check for a successful read.

Comment: @chris Well, can we close it as a dupe of [Why is iostream::eof inside a loop condition considered wrong?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong) now?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  I have deleted the iOS :: binary , it still prints out "original" instead of "five"

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I have modified the question. Please put it out of [on hold]

Comment: @DrewDormann Could you PLEASE read the question again?  Please put it out of [on hold]

Comment: You've made good edits. More importantly, πάνταῥεῖ made changes to the code so it can compile.  I voted to reopen it about 30 minutes ago. Just wait. Good luck!

Comment: @DrewDormann  Thank you all for the editing and help!  I had no idea how this works

Comment: @Kid_Learning_C Voted for reopening. Good luck ...

Comment: @Zaph Please vote for reopening

Comment: I was the first vote to reopen after the code was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

Here is example of how can you get the string from text file

```
#include <fstream>

std::string getDataFromFile(std::string filepath)
{
   ifstream fin;


   std::ifstream file(filepath);
   std::string temp;
   stringstream fileData("");
   while(std::getline(file, temp)) {
       fileData << temp << "\r\n";
   }
   file.close();

   return fileData.str();
```

}

Answer (score -2):

In the `cout` statement on line 20 (`cout << op << "haha" << endl;`) the text saying  `<< "haha"` must be deleted. Or if your intended output should equal this:

```
five
haha
```

Try doing this:

```
cout << op << endl <<"haha";
```

I do find this a simple to answer question though. I am so sorry my answer did not output correctly :(.

Comment: I don't see how this should fix the problem stated in the question?

Comment: Thanks I corrected my code. The thing that really bothers me is that ""file >> op" never worked. no string is ever loaded into op. Why is this?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  really sorry!  I am also new to stackoverflow. Now it is changed